Show variations like single products in WordPress Woocommerce online store
I am trying to write a simple plugin for Woocommerce store. Where I can list the variations like single product and hide the parent product.
I am almoste done it but the problem is that now the plugin works only for the shop arhive page. But I need it also for categories pages and other taxonomies. I can't find the way to do it.
This is the code ot my plugin.
+
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Display One Variation Per Color and Regular Products
 * Description: Displays only one variation per color and all regular products on all product listing pages, including category pages.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Atanas Kostadinov
 * Text Domain: wc-display-one-per-color-and-regular
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        // Apply only on product archives and taxonomy pages to include both regular products and variations
        if ($query->is_post_type_archive('product') || $query->is_product_taxonomy() || $query->is_shop()) {
            $query->set('post_type', ['product', 'product_variation']);
            // No need to exclude parent products, so they are also displayed
        }
    }
});

add_filter('posts_clauses', function ($clauses, $query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (in_array('product_variation', (array) $query->get('post_type'))) {
        // Modify SQL to manage product variations and ensure we display one variation per color
        if ($query->is_post_type_archive('product') || $query->is_product_taxonomy() || $query->is_shop()) {
            $clauses['fields'] .= ", MIN($wpdb->posts.ID) AS variation_id";
            $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_pa_color')";
            $clauses['groupby'] = "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value"; // Group variations by the color attribute
            $clauses['orderby'] = "variation_id ASC"; // Order by the first variation ID to display only one per color
        }
    }
    return $clauses;
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('the_title', function ($title, $id) {
    $product = wc_get_product($id);
    if ($product && $product->is_type('variation')) {
        // Modify the title to include the color attribute for variations
        return $product->get_title() . ' - ' . $product->get_attribute('color');
    }
    return $title;
}, 10, 2);


Can someone try to fix this part where the variations show also in the categories pages?
And to tell I am not so advanced.

We need to modify the logic to target all relevant pages. The current code already handles the shop archive, product taxonomies, and the main shop page, but let's refine it to ensure it applies to all product listing contexts.
Step 1:
We need to replace the given code.
// Apply only on product archives and taxonomy pages to include both regular products and variations

        if ($query->is_post_type_archive('product') || $query->is_product_taxonomy() || $query->is_shop()) {

with the given one.
// Apply to all product listing pages including archives and taxonomies

        if ($query->is_post_type_archive('product') || $query->is_tax('product_cat') || $query->is_tax('product_tag') || $query->is_shop()) {

Step 2:
We need to replace the given code.
if ($query->is_post_type_archive('product') || $query->is_product_taxonomy() || $query->is_shop()) {

with the given one.
if ($query->is_post_type_archive('product') || $query->is_tax('product_cat') || $query->is_tax('product_tag') || $query->is_shop()) {

Step 3:
Add the given code at the end of file.
add_filter( 'the_title', function ( $title, $id ) {

    $product = wc_get_product($id);

    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {

        // We have modify the title to include the color attribute for variations.

        return $product->get_title() . ' - ' . $product->get_attribute('color');

    }

    return $title;

}, 10, 2 );

